# How to enable IPv6 support in GCP cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipv6, google-cloud-build

I use GCP cloud build service to test my project built from GN. But I found the could build does not have IPv6 enabled when it run the docker image from my cloud build config file.

I was wondering if we can enable the IPv6 support in cloud build? such as how I enable the IPv6 in my local docker engine.

Edit /etc/docker/daemon.json, set the ipv6 key to true and the fixed-cidr-v6 key to your IPv6 subnet. In this example we are setting it to 2001:db8:1::/64.
{
"ipv6": true,
"fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64"
}

I don't see any configuration setting to config docker engine in cloud build, I was wondering if this is possible to enable IPv6 in could build CI/CD

Try to enable the IPv6 within the docker image, but then I realize this is controlled by the docker engine instead of docker image.

Comment: I do not believe that Docker is used by Cloud Build as the container engine. I also do not know of a method to enable IPv6 at this time.

Comment: Cloud Build uses Docker to execute builds. For each build step, Cloud Build executes a Docker container as an instance of docker run

Comment: The word **Docker** is like Xerox or FedEx. Do you have a reference that Cloud Build uses the Docker Engine? I might be wrong but I believe Cloud Build is using Knative to run containers. https://cloud.google.com/knative/

Comment: You can have a try with Cloud Build private pool. But I'm not sure that will solve the issue. IPv6 support is pretty new on Google Cloud, all the services are not yet compliant.

Comment: I am new to the cloud, my understanding is knative is to run Kubernetes, don't know it is used also to run cloud build. From the official document, it says it uses docker. 
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/overview

Comment: OK - I am wrong. I found a reference that Cloud Build uses Docker Engine 20.10.17 https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/overview#docker However, that does not solve your issue about IPv6. I am not aware of a method to enable IPv6 at this time.